# Why do we divide by the count of each letter in questions of the form "how many words can I form from the letters in"?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

For example, how many words can we form from the letters in the word google?

First I thought you counted how many different letters there are in this case 4, therefore in each spot (6 spots) there are 4 different choices. So the amount of words is $4^6$?

I found out this is wrong and instead you use the idea of a multinomial and calculate $\frac{n!}{a_1!a_2!,...,a_k!}$ where $n$ is the amount of letters in the word, here n = 6, and then $a_1="g"$ which appears twice and so forth.

Why do we divide by the $a_k!$ factorial terms? Do we not lose possible words?

Comment: "First I thought you counted how many different letters there are in this case 4, therefore in each spot (6 spots) there are 4 different choices. So the amount of words is 46?"  So according to you the word "gollog" and "geegee" are acceptable words that can be formed (even though the first has too many $L$s and the second too many $G$s but "go" is not because it doesn't have enough letters?

Comment: Haha I now see why that's silly, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you divide by $a_k!$ is to avoid multiple counting for each of the arrangements of the identical letters.

Imagine the letters $AAAMNP$. Let's affix a subscript to each of the $A$s. So you can have, for example,

$PA_1NA_2MA_3$, or

$PA_2NA_1MA_3$, or

$PA_1NA_3MA_2$, etc.

The word in each case is $PANAMA$, but simply taking $6!$ words multiple-counts $PANAMA$ six times (and every other permutation, like $AAMPNA$).

That's why you divide by the factorials of the multiplicities of the identical letters.

(Also, small difference in all of the six-letter words that can be made from the letters in GOOGLE ($6!/2!2!$) and the number of six-letter words that can be made using only G, O, L, and E ($4^6$).)

Comment: the factorial then is for all the ways to arrange i.e the A's?

Comment: Yes. For GOOGLE you'd divide by $2!$ for the Os and another $2!$ for the Gs.

Comment: Great I appreciate the response! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the word $\color{blue}G\color{red}o\color{orange}o\color{blue}g\color{green}l\color{red}e$ I rearrange that letters to get the word $\color{blue}g\color{orange}o\color{red}o\color{blue}G\color{green}l\color{red}e$.

Is that the same word or a different word?

Those are the same word.  If we did straight $6!$ we'd have those having to count as different words.  But for every word where we put the orange "O" in position $k$ and we put the red "O" is position $j$, it'd be the exact same result as if we had put the red "O" in position $k$ and the orange "O" in position $j$.

So to count those as one option and not $2$ options as there are $2!$ ways to arrange the $2$ "O"s but thar are considered to be the same, we must divide by the $2!$ ways or arrange the "O"s

Comment: Using the colors from the logo is brilliant.

Comment: But without looking them up could your remember the colors?  Would you have remembered the two "g"s are *both* blue?  *razzlefrazzle*.  but fortunately the distinction between $\color{blue}G$ and $\color{blue}g$ is clear by capitalization.

Comment: Haha no! I would have remembered simple colors, but not which ones. Anyway, an elegant way to differentiate things.